# Initramfs prompt while installing Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS or later on Dell XPS 8900

Tags: system-installation, dell, xps

[image: ACPI errors and messages about nouveau ending in FAULT, finally Busybox, initramfs prompt]

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Dell xps, but getting the below error. Same works fine on another Thinkpad laptop.

```
ACPI Error:  Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND [20170531/dswload-210]
```